# ReactJS onClick setState to different element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, and I am having a little issue. Maybe somebody can help me out.

So the issue is that I am unable to triger the element I want with onCLick function. Now I am trying to remove the navigation when

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {navStatus: "navHide"};
    }

    navClose() {
        var navOpened = document.getElementById("myNav");
        navOpened.setState({navStatus: "navHide"});
    }

    navOpen() {
        this.setState({navStatus: "navShow"});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <nav onClick={this.navOpen.bind(this)}>
                <div id="myNav" className={this.state.navStatus}>
                    <div className="navClose" onClick={this.navClose.bind(this)}>
                        <object className="navCloseBtn" type="image/svg+xml" data="svg/close.svg"></object>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

The error I am having is

```
nav.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: navOpened.setState is not a function
```

Also if you notice some patterns that I could improve in my code, I would really appreciate the feedback.

Thank You!

Comment: You should replace `navOpened.setState({navStatus: "navHide"});` by     `this.setState({navStatus: "navHide"});`

Comment: Only react components have `setState` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only react components have `setState` method.
Working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    navStatus: "navHide"
  };

  this.navClose = this.navClose.bind(this);
  this.navOpen = this.navOpen.bind(this);
}

navClose(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.setState({
    navStatus: "navHide"
  });
}

navOpen() {
  this.setState({
    navStatus: "navShow"
  });
}

render() {
  return(
    <nav onClick={this.navOpen}>
      <div id="myNav" className={this.state.navStatus}>
        <div className="navClose" onClick={this.navClose}>
          <object
            className="navCloseBtn"
            type="image/svg+xml"
            data="svg/close.svg"
          ></object>
        </div>                  
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Also you should bind event handlers in constructor instead of `render` method.

Comment: Ah, yes. It'ts because, when you are clicking at `.navClose` you are also clicking at `nav` element and `setState` is calling twice.
First call - this.setState({ navStatus: 'navHide'}).
Second call - this.setState({ navStatus: 'navShow'})

Comment: yes your event is bubbling upa and also navopen getting called 
use event.stopPropagation

Comment: Why bind `this` to the two functions in the component's constructor?  `this` will already point to the correct context because the functions are inside of the class.

Comment: @MichaelParker, no, we are passing them to `onClick` props of DOM elements. If not to bind, `this` will be equal `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Nav extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {navStatus: "navHide"};
}

navClose() {
    var navOpened = document.getElementById("myNav");
    this.setState({navStatus: "navHide"});
}

navOpen() {
    this.setState({navStatus: "navShow"});
}

render() {
    return(
        <nav onClick={this.navOpen.bind(this)}>
            <div id="myNav" className={this.state.navStatus}>
                <div className="navClose" onClick={this.navClose.bind(this)}>
                    <object className="navCloseBtn" type="image/svg+xml" data="svg/close.svg"></object>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: what is the point of `var navOpened = document.getElementById("myNav")` ?

Comment: anyway the second hanlder `navOpen` is not working, test it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use inline functions,

```
<nav onClick={() => this.setState(navStatus: "navShow")}>
```

but some argue that it has performance issue, https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dont-use-inline-arrow-functions-as-properties-e3cae2680b9d

Answer (score 0):

If you use a functional component you can use the set Functions

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
```

...

```
<Button onClick={() => setFilters([])}>Clear Filters</Button>
```