# How to bind event handler function so that it can successfully set React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing my first React app to sort the following data by column when the user clicks on the up & down arrows. Screenshot below:

[image]

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './Components/Table';
import './App.css';
import SATResultData from './SATResults.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      SATResultData: {},
      columnToSort: '',
      sortOrder: 'asc'
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({SATResultData: SATResultData});
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <main>
            <Table SATResultData={this.state.SATResultData}/>
          </main>
        );
      }
    }

export default App;
```

Here is my SATHeaderRow.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SATHeaderItem from './SATHeaderItem';

class SATHeaderRow extends Component {
  render() {
    let headerItems = this.props.headerRow.map(headerText => {
      return (
        <SATHeaderItem headerText={headerText}/>
      );
    });

    return (
      <tr>
        {headerItems}
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
export default SATHeaderRow;
```

And here is my SATHeaderItem.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import sortByColumn from '../Logic/sort';
import sorticon from './sort.svg';

class SATHeaderItem extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <th>
          {this.props.headerText} <img src={sorticon} alt="Sort ascending" onClick={sortByColumn}/>
        </th>
        )
    }
}
export default SATHeaderItem;
```

And lastly, my sort.js file is:

```
const flipSortOrder = {
  'asc': 'desc',
  'desc': 'asc'
};

export default function sortByColumn(columnName) {
  console.log('hello');
  console.log(this.state.sortOrder);
  this.setState({'sortOrder': flipSortOrder[this.state.sortOrder]});
}
```

I would like to add a onClick listener to call `sortByColumn` when `sorticon` is clicked. The function is called correctly, but throws the error "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" on the second line of `sortByColumn`. I read from other answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038521/reactjs-onclick-setstate-to-different-element) that I need to bind event handlers. However:

**Therefore, my questions are:**

1. Where do I add the `this.sortByColumn = this.sortByColumn.bind(this);` line of code? In the constructor of the `App` class, or should I create a new constructor in the `SATHeaderItem` class because that is where `sortByColumn` is being called?
2. Will the `this.setState({'sortOrder': flipSortOrder[this.state.sortOrder]});` line of code successfully flip 'asc' to 'desc' and vice versa?

Comment: `this.sortByColumn = this.sortByColumn.bind(this);` should be added in the component where the method sortByColumn resides. This method should be included in the component itself, not in an external file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick...

You don't need to even import your sort.js file just use setState directly in your component.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import sortByColumn from '../Logic/sort';
    import sorticon from './sort.svg';

    class SATHeaderItem extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               sortOrder: 'asc'
            };
        }
        render() {
          return (
            <th>
              {this.props.headerText} 
          <img src={sorticon} alt="Sort ascending" 
               onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => {(
               sortOrder: (prevState.sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc')
              )} }/>
            </th>
            )
        }
    }
    export default SATHeaderItem;
```