# Why does the setState fn needs to be called through another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets look at the code below

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [isGoingOut, setGoingOut] = React.useState(false);
    
    function yeet() {
        setGoingOut(prevValue => prevValue ? false : true);    
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="state">
            <h1 className="state--title">Do I feel like going out tonight?</h1>
            <div className="state--value" onClick={yeet}>
                <h1>{isGoingOut ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm calling the set function `setGoingOut()` through the function `yeet()`. However, if I directly call the `setGoingOut()` function as below

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [isGoingOut, setGoingOut] = React.useState(false);
    
    setGoingOut(prevValue => prevValue ? false : true);
    
    return (
        <div className="state">
            <h1 className="state--title">Do I feel like going out tonight?</h1>
            <div className="state--value" onClick={setGoingOut}>
                <h1>{isGoingOut ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

it throws an error. Is this related to the React philosophy of not letting the state be changed directly (the same reason we can't change a state variable `count` as `count++` but have to do `count + 1`?

Comment: hi not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038521/reactjs-onclick-setstate-to-different-element

Comment: When you call `setGoingOut` it makes your entire app component re-execute, thus calling `setGoingOut` again, which then causes your entire app component to re-execute again, calling `setGoingOut` again etc... When `setGoingOut` is wrapped in `yeet`, it only runs when your div is clicked, so you don't get the infinite rendering issue

Comment: It's not so much as needing to be called through another function as needing to be called with the correct parameters...

Comment: @NickParsons, I'm new to React. Could you please point me to a resource where I can understand why the entire app component re-executes without clicking the button in the infinite loop case? Shouldn't it execute _only_ when the button is clicked?

Comment: @jok The main issue is with: `setGoingOut(prevValue => prevValue ? false : true);` this calls the `setGoingOut` function (it doesn't define a new function like you are doing with `function yeet() {...}`). So `setGoingOut` will execute even without you clicking your button. I can't think of a particular source, but the default behaviour of react is that it will re-render (ie: re-execute your App function) upon every state change, which is what happens when you call `setGoingOut()` inside of your component body (causing an infinite loop).

Comment: "*Is this related to the React philosophy*" - no. It's related to the fundamental principle how event handlers work

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, you are calling `yeet` which inside change `isGoingOut` using `setGoingOut`. This will surely works

```
function yeet() {
  setGoingOut((prevValue) => (prevValue ? false : true));
}
```

In the second snippet, you are changing state directly which will create `infinite loop` and produces error as:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an
> infinite loop.

You should change state not every time, but only when user clicks the button

```
setGoingOut(prevValue => prevValue ? false : true);
```

But, If you are trying to call directly `setGoingOut` then what it will do is:

1. Pass `event` object to `setGoingOut` which will become value of `isGoingOut` and then you can't change its value because you are setting the state of `isGoingOut` as a new `event` object particularly `SyntheticEvent` that React send as an argument.

   ```
   onClick={setGoingOut}
   ```

This is not the way you should change state.

You can change state on click as:

```
<div
  className="state--value"
  onClick={() => setGoingOut((prevValue) => (prevValue ? false : true))}>
  <h1>{isGoingOut ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>
</div>
```